# PostgreSQL: syntax error while creating a table in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL, just follow the documentation at 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-table.html.
I'm trying to create a table.
This is the output:

```
postgres=# $ psql mydb
postgres=# CREATE TABLE weather ( city varchar(80), temp_lo int, temp_hi int,
                  prcp real, date date );
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: $ psql mydb
        ^
```

Could you tell me please what's wrong in syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are already in the interactive terminal called `psql`, so try this query without `$ psql mydb` at start.

Comment: I've tried that option also. I've got the same output.

Comment: Don't enter `psql` at the `psql` prompt.